# Data format conversion not happening with publishjms processor to IBM MQ in NIFI

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-nifi, ibm-mq, minify

Trying to push IBM1047 encoded messages from hdfs to IBM MQ using publishjms processor in NIFI. EBSIDIC conversions not happening properly at NIFI side which results to junk data displaying at MQ. In publishJms it always taking the default character set - 1208 at MQ side. How can we override this character set code - 500 should be expected at MQ.

Please help me on this

in publish jms we are setting up the below attributes

Message body - bytes
Character Set - IBM1047

Comment: Can you share your PublishJMS configuration? There is a `Character Set` property that I would think you could set to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

> in publish jms we are setting up the below attributes Message body -
> bytes Character Set - IBM1047

Is that the native character set (CCSID) for the application running on that server or are you forcibly changing it in your code?

By that, I mean are the characters native to IBM1047 or is your application performing the character conversion?  If your application is performing character conversion, did you set the Encoding & CCSID in the MQMD structure for that message?

Note: It is far, far better for you to put the characters in the message in the native format then let MQ do the conversion when the receiving application performs a "Get with Convert" API call.